# How to copy infinity symbol as ∞ and not as \[Infinity]

Tags: output-formatting, symbols, built-in-symbols, character-encoding

```
FromCharacterCode[8734]
(* ∞ *)
```

No matter how I copy `∞` whether as plaintext or input text or whether it is inside string like `"∞"` Mathematica always copy it as `\[Infinity]`. Even when I use `CopyToClipboard` instead of manual copying.

So everything I transfer from Mathematica here on this site looks ugly:

you get

```
"123\[Infinity]456"
{1,2,3,\[Infinity],4,5,6}
Integrate[f[x],{x,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]
```

instead of

```
"123∞456"
{1,2,3,∞,4,5,6}
Integrate[f[x],{x,-∞,∞}]
```

All instances of `∞` here in this question I had to manually overwrite with symbol `∞` that I copied from web browser.

So evidently it is possible to copy and paste `∞` correctly.

Furthermore when I copy `∞` from here and paste it in Mathematica then Mathematica interprets it correctly same as it would `\[Infinity]`.

So definitely Mathematica recognize it correctly when copied and pasted from somewhere else yet it is unable to do opposite - copy it inside Mathematica and paste it literally somewhere else.

**So my question is how to copy `∞` inside Mathematica so that after being pasted here it remains `∞` and not `\[Infinity]`.**

**Update:**

I figured out the bytes that are put into clipboard when copying `∞` in Mathematica:

```
FromCharacterCode[{92,91,73,110,102,105,110,105,116,121,93}]

(* \[Infinity] *)
```

But other software like web browser put into clipboard these bytes:

```
FromCharacterCode[{226,136,158},"UTF8"]

(* ∞ *)
```

Mathematica interprets both sequences of bytes inside clipboard as infinity after being pasted but when copying it uses only first sequence.

**So if we can write bytes data into clipboard with Mathematica then that would be an answer for my question.**

Comment: Maybe this question belongs on meta. Here's an answer of sorts: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor

Comment: See [Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/27951) or, if you can't install the add-in (eg on mobile), try the Mathematica Special Character Converter at https://steampiano.net/msc/.

Comment: @Michael E2: It is question on Mathematica - precisely, how to put `∞` into clipboard using Mathematica. If my web-browser can do it and Mathematica understands it when it is pasted into it, then Mathematica should be able to do the same. Maybe if there is a way to put something into clipboard based on bytes - something like `BinaryWrite` but writing into clipboard instead of file.

Comment: But "after being pasted here" makes it about how to use the site, a question appropriate for meta.Mma. Maybe you should clarify what you want (by editing the question).

Comment: I updated my question. I think it is a question that can belong to both topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses Python and [PyClip](https://pypi.org/project/pyclip/) inside Mathematica. `expression` is expression needed to be copied into clipboard and `rules` are rules for replacing certain symbols like `∞` or `π`...

```
expression=Integrate[\[Pi]+f[x],{x,-∞,∞}];
rules={"Infinity"->"∞","Pi"->"π"};
ExternalEvaluate["Python","import pyclip\npyclip.copy(\""<>(StringReplace[ToString[expression],rules])<>"\")"]
Clear[expression,rules]
```

Then using `Paste[]` returns in Mathematica (as desired):

```
Integrate[π + f[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

Or pressing `CTRL+V` in windows in webbrowser paste as desired:

```
Integrate[π + f[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```